# What other cryptocurrency has implemented the RandomX PoW for mining?

Tags: mining, proof-of-work, loki, random-x, random-xl

With the move to RandomX for PoW mining on Monero, what other coins have forked RandomX into their coin? I know Loki has done it with RandomXL but have any others implemented it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wownero and Loki are the only other currencies I know of that plan on, or are currently implementing, *variants* of RandomX.

Comment: Arweave, that sponsored the first audit, is planning to implement it too.